# Facebook likebox and like button not showing

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

1. I am using facebook likebox.
2. It is working fine.
3. When user set him/her profile as facebook page then it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible for page. and we cant do that it's only for user profile funtionality.

Happy coding :)